# <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> to be replaced to <?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

How to achieve this in dataweave 2.0 in mulesoft ?

to be replaced to

Comment: That's unclear what you are going to do.

Comment: Keep the title clean. Perhaps "Replace single quotes to double quotes in dataweave". Add the details to the question itself. Also, please include sample input and expected output.

Comment: You don't need to do anything, just run Data weave script with `application/xml`, this will automatically produce the required XML output

Comment: My suggestion is about your title and the ask. Always try to explain your objective by being a little descriptive in the body section. Don't put everything in the title entirely. If possible also provide what you have tried before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the replacement:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java

var str1 = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
---
{
    str: str1 replace "'" with("\"")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more transform message.
Put the below-mentioned data wave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
(payload.^raw as String) replace ("version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'") with ("version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"")
```